# Listing elements from set builder notation $\Bbb Z_0'= \{x \in \Bbb Z\,|\, x=km \text{ for any } k \in \Bbb Z\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $m$ be any fixed positive integer and $\Bbb Z_0= \{x \in \Bbb Z\,|\, x=km \text{ for some } k \in \Bbb Z\}$.

In the above "$\text{for some k}\in \Bbb Z$" is an existential quantifier denoted by, $\exists k\in \Bbb Z$
Then we can list elements from the set builder notation as the following:

[$\Bbb Z_0 = \{0, \pm m, \pm2m, \pm3m, \ldots\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609088/how-to-list-elements-of-bbb-z-j-x-in-bbb-z-x-j-km-text-for-some-k)

If we change the existential quantifier to universal quantifier such as'for any k $\in \Bbb Z$', 'for every k $\in \Bbb Z$', 'for all k $\in \Bbb Z$' denoted by $\forall k \in \Bbb Z$, the set builder notation is as the following:

$\Bbb Z_0'= \{x \in \Bbb Z\,|\, x=km \text{ for any } k \in \Bbb Z\}$

Then it brings up a question. How do we list elements of $\Bbb Z_0'= \{x \in \Bbb Z\,|\, x=km \text{ for any } k \in \Bbb Z\}$?

FYI

"Definition 6 Let F be an arbitrary family of sets. The union of the sets in F, denoted by $\bigcup\mathscr F$, is the set of all elements that are in A for some $A\in\mathscr F$.​

$\bigcup\limits_{A \in \mathscr F}A$={$x\in U$|$x \in A$ for some $A\in \mathscr F$}"

"Definition 7 Let F be an arbitrary family of sets. The intersection of sets in F, denoted by $\bigcap\limits_{A\in\mathscr F}A$ or $\bigcap\mathscr F$, is the set of all elements that are in A for all $A \in\mathscr F$.​
"
$\bigcap\limits_{A\in\mathscr F}A$={$x\in U$| x∈A for all $A\in \mathscr F$}

Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_0'=\emptyset$

Comment: @sigmabe I don't understand why it leads to the empty set. Can you explain that?

Comment: If $x\in \mathbb{Z}_0'$ than every integer divides $x$. Do you know such a $x$?

Comment: In your logic, then in $\Bbb Z_0 = \{0, \pm m, \pm2m, \pm3m, \ldots\}$ 0 divides 0, 1 divides m, 2 divides 2m, 3 divides 3m... Doesn't it mean k can be every integer dividing x=km?

Comment: No, that is your logic. In my logic $2$ divides $2m$, $3$ divides $3m$ etc.